# Extract attributes from R list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I fear I'm missing something obvious but . . . I have a list in R with structure

```
List of 752
 $ : Named chr "金銀"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "名詞"
 $ : Named chr "吹替"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "名詞"
 $ : Named chr "献言"
```

It's easy enough to get the top level of the list with unlist(my_object). But how can I capture the attributes? I can use unlist(attributes(my_object[[n]])) for each element n. But surely there's a quick way to get this into a data frame. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

```
lapply(yourlist, attributes)
```

will apply the `attributes` function to each element in yourlist

Comment: Wonderful . . . and obvious in retrospect. I need to remember  . . . "if you're thinking of a loop . . . the answer is lapply"

Comment: @MarkR It certainly does take a while to get into that mindset but once you're there it's amazing how often `lapply` is a solution to your problems.

Comment: Does not solve deep-nested list, which would require recursive *apply

Comment: @ElieKerArno Sure but that's not what this question was asking about